# Updates to made for logback.xml file after version change of Splunk-libary-javalogging to 1.7.2+

Tags: spring, logback, slf4j

after version 1.7.2+ for Splunk-libary-javalogging, it appears to be throwing some error for the previous logback.xml file.

What function or syntax needs to be changed to make it work in version 1.7.2+, for to run as expected

Comment: is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/75257413/4418?

Comment: What did you change? What worked before that isn't now? What error(s) are you receiving? What does your logback.xml file look like (before and after updating this external tool)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.